# Why is the postman post request sent to my Sails.js server hosted on Heroku returning a cors preflight error when the headers have been set?

Tags: node.js, express, cors, in-app-purchase, sails.js

I've been trying to send a 200 status from my Sails.js server in response to a demo POST webhook request from IAPhub, an in app purchase API, (which is necessary to start testing it with my Android app) but it wasn't working, so I tried to test it using postman.

This is the controller method:

```
    getInAppPurchase: async function (req, res) { 
            req.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        req.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
        if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
            res.send("success")
        } else {

        // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        res.send('Success 1')
        res.end()           
        }

    }
```

This is the route:

```
'POST /inapppurchases/getInAppPurchase' : 'InAppPurchaseController.getInAppPurchase'
```

This is my CORS security configuration in config/security.js:

```
cors: {
  allRoutes: true,
  allowOrigins: '*',
  allowCredentials: false
}
```

This is my app url that the demo webhook is being sent to in postman (the number in the URL is different from the original for security purposes. (cors config in config/security.js is open to all routes so my server is not that secure)
http://mighty-app-46232519.herokuapp.com/inapppurchases/getInAppPurchase

I'm only a junior level developer so most of this stuff is new to me, but I've tried a lot of different things over the last few hours and nothing is working. I'm getting the error message as follows:

XHttpXMLRequest from origin 'https://meeting-appppp.postman.co' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've tried the following things:

1. Add

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
```

to both req and res objects

2. Check if method is the pre-flight Options request

```
if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
```

3. Sending the 200 status code back to the webhook origin which is the goal in the first place ("send" automatically sends the 200 status code as I understand it)

```
res.send("success")
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your route like this:  `POST   /inapppurchases/getInAppPurchase':  { action: 'InAppPurchaseController/getInAppPurchase', csrf: false }`